# Where in pg_catalog is the database or catalog information stored about relations?

Tags: postgresql, information-schema, system-tables, catalogs

When I query a table like `information_schema.tables`

```
SELECT
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

I get a result like this,

```
 table_catalog |    table_schema    |              table_name               
---------------+--------------------+---------------------------------------
 myDB          | mySchema           | myTable
```

I can get `table_schema`, and `table_name` from `pg_catalog.tables`, but how would I get the `table_catalog`. Where is a the `_catalog` information stored in the `pg_catalog` schema?

Answer (score 1):

You can't it's hard coded. The `_catalog` columns in the table schema literally cast from a call to [`current_database()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html)

```
CAST(current_database() AS sql_identifier) AS table_catalog,
```

You can see them defined in the source code [`postgres/src/backend/catalog/information_schema.sql`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/fd1a421fe66173fb9b85d3fe150afde8e812cbe4/src/backend/catalog/information_schema.sql)

---

The docs on [`information_schema_catalog_name`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-information-schema-catalog-name.html) make it explicit

> `information_schema_catalog_name` is a table that **always contains one row and one column containing the name of the current database** (current catalog, in SQL terminology).

The docs on [`information_schema.tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-tables.html) also say,

> Name of the database that contains the table **(always the current database)**